# Paypal REST API for Donations

Tags: paypal, donations

I'm trying to create a custom form with the ability to process credit card direct donations, as well as paypal account donations, and the ability to select whether the amount paid is a regular monthly donation or a one time.  I cannot find documentation anywhere on how to use the paypal REST API for donations.  There doesn't seem to be an intent type for donation anywhere, or any option for monthly or one time payments.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  I understand how the commercial payment API works, but I'm not sure what options need to be changed for donations.

Comment: You don't have to do anything special for donations.  It's just a payment like any other.

Comment: I was going to ask this exact same question but was afraid I had missed something myself. I also have found nothing on this.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, and what about recurring payments, is there an option to set for that?  Can it be done with the REST API or do I have to use the recurring payment classic API?

Comment: actually it's not like any others, the generated url makes the user land on a paypal page where he can put both the credit card data and login info, in a donation page, while on a payment page only the login is present

Comment: We would need a way to edit the experience. There's a similar question here. It just needs an answer for the v2 API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42160816/paypal-checkout-dont-ask-for-delivery-address-for-non-members

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to add [Buy Now](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_singleitem-intro-outside) button to your site. It is just plain HTML code, no server code is needed. When someone donated you recieve email with details including amount of payment and email of donator. So you can reply him "Thank you" :)
Please note, in some countries you should verify your paypal account before accepting payments. It can be done in "View limits" menu.